# Is it possible to migrate the health and usage collection database to a new farm?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, migration

I'm performing a migration of SharePoint from 2013 farm to a new 2016 farm (on a different AD domain) and I would need the collected analytics data (usage, views) to be kept, therefor, is it possible and compatible to migrate the "Health and Usage" database containing this data ?

If not possible, are there any alternatives to migrate the content related to documents analytics ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the default Usage and Health Data Collection database will be installed when running the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard in a new farm.

And it is recommended to configure new settings such as usage and health data collection, diagnostic logging, and mobile accounts.

If necessary, you could restore the old logging database in new farm and then use following powershell to point the Usage and Health data collection service application to the old database:

```
Set-SPUsageApplication -Identity "<ServiceApplicationName>" -DatabaseName "<DbName>" -DatabaseServer "<SQLServerName>"
```

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/move-or-rename-service-application-databases#to-point-the-usage-and-health-data-collection-service-application-to-a-moved-database-by-using-powershell